While running docker, Selenium Grid browser images are disabled and shows Error
How to resolve below error:

6 requests waiting for a slot to be free. Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, moz:firefoxOptions: {args: [--headless, --window-size=1920,1080], prefs: {}}}Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, moz:firefoxOptions: {args: [--headless

